# Не передается токен JWT Bearer с внешнего сервиса авторизации на основной сервис

Tags: c#, авторизация, .net-core, jwt

Есть два сервиса основной и второстепенный. Не передается токен JWT с внешнего сервиса авторизации на основной сервис. Второстепенный должен передать токен на основной, но в заголовке его нет. При запросе на основной сервис авторизации заголовок авторизации есть и валидация токена проходит в middleware. `var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();` получение токена на основном сервисе авторизации. Передача параметров на второстепенном: `options.Authority = "http://localhost:5282/"; options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; options.Audience = "MyAuthClient"; options.SaveToken = true;`
Может нужен еще параметр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запуск 2 visual studio режет заголовки пакетов на localhost. Один из проектов нужно запускать через exe.

Comment: Поставил плюсик, так как очень ценю когда автор проблемы делится решением. То что ваше обходное решение рабочее, сомневаться не приходится. Но то что проблема именно в студии и её нельзя решить продолжая её использовать как-то не верится.